# MacOS pycharm can not install python Mediapipe version 0.10.0 with pip

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

I am trying to install the latest version of mediapipe 0.10.0 using `pip install mediapipe==0.10.0` but always I get the same error:
*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.10.0 (from versions: 0.8.3.1, 0.8.4.2, 0.8.5, 0.8.6.2, 0.8.7.1, 0.8.7.2, 0.8.7.3, 0.8.8, 0.8.8.1, 0.8.9, 0.8.9.1, 0.8.10, 0.8.10.1, 0.8.11, 0.9.0, 0.9.0.1, 0.9.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.10.0*

I tried python versions 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and none of them worked.
Although the previous version is always installed without error.

I used pip from terminal and from pycharm managing packages

Comment: What is your OS version? What is the output if you run `import distutils; print(distutils.util.get_platform())` in python?

Comment: If [this is you](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/4512), i.e. you have MacOs version 11.7.6, then the `pip` output is corerct. current mediapipe whl files require a MacOs >=12 to be installed

Comment: Yes it me.
I will try it and come back to you

Comment: @FlyingTeller I upgraded my Mac OS to Ventura 13.4 and became able to install mediapipe 0.10.0 successfully. Thanks again and sorry if I interrupted your flying journey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version in the list of available ones `0.9.1.0`, so to investigate where the issue might be, we can check for any differences in the releases. For this, we can check the `files` section of the [PyPi project page](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe):

For [0.10.0](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.10.0/#files) (which `pip` doesn't see compatible for you):

> mediapipe-0.10.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_universal2.whl
> mediapipe-0.10.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_universal2.whl
> mediapipe-0.10.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_universal2.whl
> mediapipe-0.10.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_12_0_universal2.whl

For [0.9.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.9.2.1/#files) (which `pip` doesn't see compatible for you):

> mediapipe-0.9.2.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.2.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.2.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.2.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_12_0_x86_64.whl

For [0.9.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.9.1.0/#files) (which `pip` does see compatible for you):

> mediapipe-0.9.1.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.1.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.1.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
> mediapipe-0.9.1.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl

Now we can check differences. All python tags are the same `cp38`, `cp39`, `cp310`, `cp311`, so as long as you are using python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 or 3.11 it is compatible. The difference is the platform tag.

For version 0.9.1, the tag is `macosx_10_15` indicating a compatibility with MacOS version >= 10.15

For 0.9.2.1, the tag is `macosx_12_0`, so we now have a compatibility with MacOS version >= 12

You have most likely a lower version, so you cannot install the more recent mediapipe versions. Upgrade your OS and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/), the `mediapipe` package is supported on all operating systems (including MacOS) and the above-specified Python versions.

Try upgrading your pip version first by running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and verify the update by checking the `pip --version`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already done that (pip --version 23.1.2) and still has no effect.
On strange thing I noticed that in pycharm packages you can see that the latest version is 0.10.0 but when I try to install it I get the error again.